# Getting first object inside JSON

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'll cut straight to the chase. I'm getting a json object with another object inside of it like so:

```
function getName(summonerName, region) {
    LolApi.Summoner.getByName(summonerName, region, function(err, summoner) {
        if(!err) {
            console.log(summoner);
        }
    });
}
```

However, the result of this call is (let's stay summonerName is "tetsii"):

```
{ tetsii: 
  { id: 51520537,
    name: 'tetsii',
    profileIconId: 23,
    summonerLevel: 23,
    revisionDate: 1408307600000
  }
}
```

Now, I can access the id's and stuff with "console.log(summoner.tetsii.id)" for example, but because the summonerName (in this case "tetsii") can be anything, I prefer not to do it like so. So, my question is: how to access the first object inside a JSON or is there another way? And no, I can't get an array in this case afaik.

I would like to note that I've tried "console.log(summoner.summonerName.id)", but that doesn't yield results as summonerName is a string.

Thanks everybody

EDIT: Got the answer. By simply using summoner[summonerName].id I am able to grab the id. Thanks everyone for answers!

-Tetsii

Comment: Have you tried `summoner["summonerName"].id`, or if `summonerName` is a variable holding a string, `summoner[summonerName].id`?

Comment: the latter worked! awesome! thank you mister.

Answer (score 0):

By using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). For example, if you know that `summoner` will only have a single top-level key, you can get it with:

```
var summonerName = Object.keys(summoner)[0];
```

Obligatory browser support notice: IE < 9 does not support this out of the box, but you can use a polyfill provided in the MDN page as a compatibility shim.

Comment: Also, strictly speaking, property order is not guaranteed; this is no problem if there's only one of course.

Comment: @Ja͢ck How have you got an arrow under your name?

Answer (score 0):

There is no order in objects, so there's no guarantee you'll get the object you think, but using Object.keys and shift() you can do

```
var first = summoner[Object.keys(summoner).shift()];
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no way to return it as an array, the best idea is to iterate over the object properties as documented in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

The most important part is:

```
for (var prop in summoner) {
  console.log("summoner." + prop + " = " + summoner[prop]);
}
```

Tested in console:

```
var summoner = { tetsii: 
  { id: 51520537,
    name: 'tetsii',
    profileIconId: 23,
    summonerLevel: 23,
    revisionDate: 1408307600000
  }
};
```

yields:

```
summoner.tetsii = [object Object]
```